# Do you need to clean inside of a window air condtioner?

Tags: air-conditioning

I've been living in an apartment for about 6 years now. I've never used a window AC installed in this unit.

I just cleaned up the filter and started using it a week ago and I cough more than usual. I suspect that it's possible that mold or dirt grew up in the air conditioner, but I have no idea how an AC works inside.

Do you need to clean inside of a window AC?

I live in an area that receives a week of rain in a year and it gets a bit humid between July and September.

Comment: Yes. most window AC's can be removed from the housing and cleaned. However, if you're renting, have your landlord or building superintendent do that, because it is the property owner's equipment, because disassembly is heavy and dirty work, and because *you* would be responsible for any damage done if you try to clean it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window ac units usually only have a particulate/ dust filter to keep the dust out of the evaporator coil.

If the filter is intact cleaning it is all that is normally needed in a window unit.

If you want to do additional cleaning remove the filter to access the evaporator coil.

Use a non acid cleaner even a spray bottle with clear water or a cleaner like simple green will usually be enough.

Make sure the unit has a slight tilt to the outside this is normal so the condensate can drain out the back, the rinse or cleaner will do the same.

Some people are affected by the dry air that is created with air conditioning this can also be the reason for your cough , if not ringing and or cleaning the coil would remove any buildup in the fins.

There are also commercial evaporator cleaners these are usually about 10-15$ per can I don’t usually suggest these on a small unit as they can make a mess and drip inside, if you use a spray can of coil cleaner make sure to have something to catch the drips just in case.